# Embed PowerBI DashBoard

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am getting MFA issue.Because of I didn't login the powerbi, but i given all requirements in postman it still throwing this issue. Can anyone guide me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance

Error:
"error": "interaction_required",

"error_description": "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID: 8c1d6536-4242-4dae-a53d-e332086f5700\r\nCorrelation ID: 1c048967-e8c5-4264-88d0-191deb8da125\r\nTimestamp: 2021-06-09 09:30:11Z",

Answer (score 0):

This error is because "Security defaults" is enabled for Your tenant. Disable it by Navigating to Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> Properties -> Click on Manage Security Defaults links -> Toggle Enable Security Defaults links button to NO

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults